# Обращение к элементу списка по индексу: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, int, type-error, range

Пробую обратиться к элементу списка по индексу, причём уверен, что это именно список, не целое число, а мне в ответ `'int' object is not subscriptable`

```
a,b=map(int,input().split())
c=[]
for x in range(a):
    for y in range(b):
        c.append(10*x+y)
for x in range(a):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        for y in range(b):
            print(c[x][y],end=' ')
    elif x%2==1:
        for y in range(b-1,-1,-1):
            print(c[x][y],end=' ')
```

Выводит всегда это:

```
print(c[x][y],end=' ')
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

А по коду видно, что c - это никакой не инт, а список, и обратиться к его элементу по индексу всё равно не даёт. Что делать?

Comment: по коду видно, что список одномерный, а программист хочет обратиться к нему, как к двумерному

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c` - это список, а вот `c[x]`, к которому вы по индексу `y` обращаетесь в `c[x][y]`, это уже конкрентый элемент из `c`, то есть `int`.

> Что делать?

Определиться с тем, что у вас хранится в `c` - целые или списки, и работать с ними соответственно.